# Show Product Code on Order Management Admin Page Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop

How to show product code data on Order Management Page admin in Prestashop 
I am lost in files. Please help me
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution,
I don't know its allow or not to answer your own question here
but I post this answer with this hope that it will help someone

I chage the query on AdminOrdersController.php

Full Link is >>> myshop/controllers/admin/AdminOrdersController.php

```
$this->_select = '
        od.product_name AS products_zee,         /* This is the main thing which I changed */
        a.id_currency,
        a.id_order AS id_pdf,
        CONCAT(LEFT(c.`firstname`, 1), \'. \', c.`lastname`) AS `customer`,
        osl.`name` AS `osname`,
        os.`color`,
        IF((SELECT COUNT(so.id_order) FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'orders` so WHERE so.id_customer = a.id_customer) > 1, 0, 1) as new';

        $this->_join = '
        LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'order_detail` od ON (od.`id_order` = a.`id_order`)
        LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'customer` c ON (c.`id_customer` = a.`id_customer`)
        LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'address` addr ON (a.`id_address_delivery` = addr.`id_address`)
        LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'order_state` os ON (os.`id_order_state` = a.`current_state`)
        LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'order_state_lang` osl ON (os.`id_order_state` = osl.`id_order_state` AND osl.`id_lang` = '.(int)$this->context->language->id.')';
        $this->_orderBy = 'id_order';
        $this->_orderWay = 'DESC';
```

After that I add array after this code

```
'reference' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('Reference'),
            'align' => 'center',
            'width' => 65
 ),


'products_zee' => array(
    'title' => $this->l('Products'),
    'align' => 'center',
    'width' => 85
),
```